# Silverlight IApplicationService equivalent for winRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I started porting windows phone 7 application to windows 8, They are using IApplicationService inherited class for start an stop services. How i can achieve the same in windows 8. I am attaching the windows phone code below. Please help me. Its a blocking section seems bit difficult.

```
      public class ApplicationService : IApplicationService
      {
           private IApplicationService _logger;
           private IApplicationService _dataSourceManager;
           public void StartService(ApplicationServiceContext context)
           {
                  _logger = new Logger();
                  _dataSourceManager = new DataSourceManager();
                  _logger.StartService(context);
                  _dataSourceManager.StartService(context);
           }  
           private IApplicationService LoadService(string assemblyName, string typename)
           {
                    var parts = Deployment.Current.Parts;
                    if (parts.Any(part => part.Source.StartsWith(assemblyName)))
                    {
                             var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
                             Type type = assembly.GetType(typename);
                             return Activator.CreateInstance(type, new[] {   
                             SynchronizationContext.Current }) as IApplicationService;
                    }
                    return null;
           }
           public void StopService()
          {
                  Current.StopService();
                 _dataSourceManager.StopService();
                 _logger.StopService(); // stop last because other services depend on it
                 _logger = null;
                 _dataSourceManager = null;
           }
}
```